# Shutil : Unable to set flag properly or Move/copy all files of matched pattern in one move

Tags: python, file, shutil

I am tried to move files w.r.t some pattern from one location to some random location. And want to set `Ismoved` flag after moving the files of particular pattern.

Let say I have a SQL table like this

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
id |  pattern | source_dir        |  dest_loc      | IsMoved |  files eg
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  |  abc     |  c:\\food         | d:\\wood       |     0   | abc1,abc2,abc3
------------------------------------------------------------------------
2  |  pqr     |  c:\\food         | d:\\wood       |     0   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
3  |  xyz     |  c:\\food\\sweet  | d:\\wood       |     0   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
4  |  mln     |  c:\\food\\sweet  | d:\\wood       |     0   |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Code :**

```
import os
import shutil

src_files = os.listdir(src)
files=[f for f in allfiles if str(f).startswith(pattern)]

for file_name in files:
    full_file_name = os.path.join(src, file_name)
    if (os.path.isfile(full_file_name)):
        shutil.copy(full_file_name, dest)
        logger.info('File Moved successfully: '+filename)
        qry1="update wdtab set IsMoved=1 where id="+str(id)
        cursor.execute(qry1)
        cnxn.commit()
    else:
        logger.info('File Not exits: '+filename)
```

I'm unable to move all files of  particular file in one move. How can I do that, so that I can set my flag after all those files get moved/copied?

Comment: "move all files of particular file in one move": what do you mean by that?

Comment: Note: for the future and generally proper use of SQL in code, you may want to use parameter substitution, instead of concatenating the stringified `id` (similar for logging, e.g. `logger.info('File does not exist: %s', filename)`).

Comment: `filename` is an undefined variable (similar `dest` and `src`, but I assume these are obtained magically from the database table). Perhaps you wanted `filename = shutil.copy(full_file_name, dest)` (works only with Python 3)?

Comment: @Evert Im looking for something to move bulk group of file in a group. so said in one move

Comment: Your current code just loops through a list of filenames to copy to a directory: what's wrong with that? Practically, any bulk copy would do the same under the hood.

Comment: You mention "move", but your example shows "copy". Those are different things; please be clear which one you want.

Comment: Any one is okay, lets go for copy first

Comment: You need to be clear what *exactly* is not working (other than the fact that your code example is incomplete). You can't move a list of files with one command: just create a loop around that, which is what you've already done. So I don't understand what your problem is.